# Return Dataset in EF with federated database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure-sql-database

I want to execute a store procedure in EF with Azure federated database. i want to execute store procedure with filtering on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DataSet dataToReturn = null;  DataSet dataToReturn = null;

                using (var temp = new DataSet())
                {
                    var useFederationCommandText = BuildUSEFederation(fedID);

                    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ATCommon.DSN))
                    {
                        connection.Open();

                        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
                        {
                            command.CommandText = useFederationCommandText;
                            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }

                        SqlParameter[] sqlparams = {
                             new SqlParameter("@USERID",userId), 
                             new SqlParameter("@BASESTARTDATE",baseStartDate), 
                             new SqlParameter("@BASEENDDATE",baseEndDate),
                             new SqlParameter("@CASETYPEID",caseType), 
                             new SqlParameter("@GROUPTYPE",groupType)
                                };
                        using (var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
                        {
                            using (var command = new SqlCommand("TrendUserGraphTest"))
                            {
                                foreach (var param in sqlparams)
                                {
                                    command.Parameters.Add(param);
                                }

                                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                                command.Connection = connection;
                                //command.CommandText = strSql;
                                dataAdapter.SelectCommand = command;
                                dataAdapter.Fill(temp);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    dataToReturn = temp;
                }
```

Comment: 3 minutes to answer... ha, strange.